# How to expose port in Red Hat Firewall

Tags: java, http, azure, virtual-machine, port

I have created Red Hat VM in Microsoft Azure.

I have started Java server in VM with port 8081 and it started successfully. But I am not able view it in browser. Its doesn't get loaded.

I am using Red Hat Linux OS. I believe Firewall is blocking the Port to be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Red Hat, you should open port 8081 on Azure NSG (Inbound rules), you also need to add rules to Red Hat firewall. You could use the following commands:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8081/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

More information about Red Hat firewall please refer to this [article](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html).